# Extracting image from PDF with /CCITTFaxDecode filter

Tags: image, pdf, itext, extract

I have a pdf that was generated from scanning software. The pdf has 1 TIFF image per page. I want to extract the TIFF image from each page.

I am using iTextSharp and I have successfully found the images and can get back the raw bytes from the `PdfReader.GetStreamBytesRaw` method. The problem is, as many before me have discovered, iTextSharp does not contain a `PdfReader.CCITTFaxDecode` method.

What else do I know? Even without iTextSharp I can open the pdf in notepad and find the streams with `/Filter /CCITTFaxDecode` and I know from the `/DecodeParams` that it is using CCITTFaxDecode group 4.

Does anyone out there know how I can get the CCITTFaxDecode filter images out of my pdf?

Comment: in case anybody is interested in a solely iTextSharp solution, there's this other link (http://kuujinbo.info/iTextSharp/CCITTFaxDecodeExtract.aspx) that suggests using a new feature introduced in iTextSharp 5xx called Parser - it actually works. credits to @kuunjinbo
it's just that in my case i had to use ImageConverter on the result to create a Bitmap out of it (not sure why)

Comment: If you follow the code through from the parser, it ultimately calls the TIFFFaxDecompressor class... which seems very flawed.  it ignores some of the flags it is given, and doesn't, for example, even attempt an implementation when Height=0

Answer (score 18):

Actually, vbcrlfuser's answer did help me, but the code was not quite correct for the current version of BitMiracle.LibTiff.NET, as I could download it. In the current version, equivalent code looks like this:

```
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using BitMiracle.LibTiff.Classic;

...
      Tiff tiff = Tiff.Open("C:\\test.tif", "w");
      tiff.SetField(TiffTag.IMAGEWIDTH, UInt32.Parse(pd.Get(PdfName.WIDTH).ToString()));
      tiff.SetField(TiffTag.IMAGELENGTH, UInt32.Parse(pd.Get(PdfName.HEIGHT).ToString()));
      tiff.SetField(TiffTag.COMPRESSION, Compression.CCITTFAX4);
      tiff.SetField(TiffTag.BITSPERSAMPLE, UInt32.Parse(pd.Get(PdfName.BITSPERCOMPONENT).ToString()));
      tiff.SetField(TiffTag.SAMPLESPERPIXEL, 1);
      tiff.WriteRawStrip(0, raw, raw.Length);
      tiff.Close();
```

Using the above code, I *finally* got a valid Tiff file in C:\test.tif. Thank you, vbcrlfuser!

Comment: What's `raw`?  Could you show the complete example.

Comment: B.K. this might be a tad late, but I would guess it is this. see vbcrlfuser's answer... byte[] data = PdfReader.GetStreamBytesRaw((PRStream)pdfStream); (used in the same way as raw)

Answer (score 9):

This library... http://www.bitmiracle.com/libtiff/ and this example below should get you 99% of the way there

```
string filter = pd.Get(PdfName.FILTER).ToString();
string width = pd.Get(PdfName.WIDTH).ToString();
string height = pd.Get(PdfName.HEIGHT).ToString();
string bpp = pd.Get(PdfName.BITSPERCOMPONENT).ToString();

switch (filter)
{
   case "/CCITTFaxDecode":

      byte[] data = PdfReader.GetStreamBytesRaw((PRStream)pdfStream);
      int tiff = TIFFOpen("example.tif", "w");
      TIFFSetField(tiff, (uint)BitMiracle.LibTiff.Classic.TiffTag.IMAGEWIDTH,(uint)Int32.Parse(width));
      TIFFSetField(tiff, (uint)BitMiracle.LibTiff.Classic.TiffTag.IMAGEHEIGHT, (uint)Int32.Parse(height));
      TIFFSetField(tiff, (uint)BitMiarcle.LibTiff.Classic.TiffTag.COMPRESSION, (uint)BitMiracle.Libtiff.Classic.Compression.CCITTFAX4);
      TIFFSetField(tiff, (uint)BitMiracle.LibTiff.Classic.TiffTag.BITSPERSAMPLE, (uint)Int32.Parse(bpp));
      TIFFSetField(tiff, (uint)BitMiarcle.Libtiff.Classic.TiffTag.SAMPLESPERPIXEL,1 );

      IntPtr pointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(data.length);
      Marshal.copy(data, 0, pointer, data.length);
      TIFFWriteRawStrip(tiff, 0, pointer, data.length);
      TIFFClose(tiff);

      break;




      break;

}
```

Comment: And the NuGet here: [BitMiracle.LibTiff.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BitMiracle.LibTiff.NET/).

Answer (score 8):

Here is python implementation:

```py
import PyPDF2
import struct

"""
Links:
PDF format: http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf
CCITT Group 4: https://www.itu.int/rec/dologin_pub.asp?lang=e&id=T-REC-T.6-198811-I!!PDF-E&type=items
Extract images from pdf: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693820/extract-images-from-pdf-without-resampling-in-python
Extract images coded with CCITTFaxDecode in .net: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641770/extracting-image-from-pdf-with-ccittfaxdecode-filter
TIFF format and tags: http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/faq.html
"""


def tiff_header_for_CCITT(width, height, img_size, CCITT_group=4):
    tiff_header_struct = '<' + '2s' + 'h' + 'l' + 'h' + 'hhll' * 8 + 'h'
    return struct.pack(tiff_header_struct,
                       b'II',  # Byte order indication: Little indian
                       42,  # Version number (always 42)
                       8,  # Offset to first IFD
                       8,  # Number of tags in IFD
                       256, 4, 1, width,  # ImageWidth, LONG, 1, width
                       257, 4, 1, height,  # ImageLength, LONG, 1, lenght
                       258, 3, 1, 1,  # BitsPerSample, SHORT, 1, 1
                       259, 3, 1, CCITT_group,  # Compression, SHORT, 1, 4 = CCITT Group 4 fax encoding
                       262, 3, 1, 0,  # Threshholding, SHORT, 1, 0 = WhiteIsZero
                       273, 4, 1, struct.calcsize(tiff_header_struct),  # StripOffsets, LONG, 1, len of header
                       278, 4, 1, height,  # RowsPerStrip, LONG, 1, lenght
                       279, 4, 1, img_size,  # StripByteCounts, LONG, 1, size of image
                       0  # last IFD
                       )

pdf_filename = 'scan.pdf'
pdf_file = open(pdf_filename, 'rb')
cond_scan_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
for i in range(0, cond_scan_reader.getNumPages()):
    page = cond_scan_reader.getPage(i)
    xObject = page['/Resources']['/XObject'].getObject()
    for obj in xObject:
        if xObject[obj]['/Subtype'] == '/Image':
            """
            The  CCITTFaxDecode filter decodes image data that has been encoded using
            either Group 3 or Group 4 CCITT facsimile (fax) encoding. CCITT encoding is
            designed to achieve efficient compression of monochrome (1 bit per pixel) image
            data at relatively low resolutions, and so is useful only for bitmap image data, not
            for color images, grayscale images, or general data.

            K < 0 --- Pure two-dimensional encoding (Group 4)
            K = 0 --- Pure one-dimensional encoding (Group 3, 1-D)
            K > 0 --- Mixed one- and two-dimensional encoding (Group 3, 2-D)
            """
            if xObject[obj]['/Filter'] == '/CCITTFaxDecode':
                if xObject[obj]['/DecodeParms']['/K'] == -1:
                    CCITT_group = 4
                else:
                    CCITT_group = 3
                width = xObject[obj]['/Width']
                height = xObject[obj]['/Height']
                data = xObject[obj]._data  # sorry, getData() does not work for CCITTFaxDecode
                img_size = len(data)
                tiff_header = tiff_header_for_CCITT(width, height, img_size, CCITT_group)
                img_name = obj[1:] + '.tiff'
                with open(img_name, 'wb') as img_file:
                    img_file.write(tiff_header + data)
                #
                # import io
                # from PIL import Image
                # im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(tiff_header + data))
pdf_file.close()
```

Comment: According to tag and question body, the op uses iTextSharp. A *python realization*, therefore, does not answer this question.

Comment: According to the TIFF specification ([link](http://www.itu.int/itudoc/itu-t/com16/tiff-fx/docs/tiff6.html)), I think that your variable `tiff_header_struct` should read `'<' + '2s' + 'H' + 'L' + 'H' + 'HHLL' * 8 + 'L'`. Note in particular the `'L'` at the end.

Answer (score 2):

It has been written [extension](https://github.com/gheeres/PDFSharp.Extensions) for this (c#).

```
PdfDictionary item;
if (item.IsImage()) {
  Image image = item.ToImage();
}
```

Comment: Actually this extension works nicely and correctly. There have been a lot of work done here. So I recommend to use this one instead of writing your own code.