# How to extract charts/tables/graphs from PDF files using Python?

Tags: python, pdf, python-3.6, ocr, extract

Searched quite a bit but as I couldn't find a solution for this kind of problem, hence posting a clear question on the same. Most answers cover image/text extraction which are comparatively easier.

I've a requirement of extracting tables and graphs as text (csv) and images respectively from PDFs.

Can anyone help me with an efficient python 3.6 code to solve the same?

Till now I could achieve extracting jpgs using startmark = b"\xff\xd8" and endmark = b"\xff\xd9", but not all tables and graphs in a PDF are plain jpgs, hence my code fails badly in achieving that.

Example, I want to extract table from page 11 and graphs from page 12 as image or something which is feasible from the below given link. How to go about it?

https://hartmannazurecdn.azureedge.net/media/2369/annual-report-2017.pdf

Comment: Hi Aakash,
Curious to know how you managed to accomplish this. Especially identifying/extracting charts and graphs.

Comment: Hi Aakash, I'm in need of the same code, to extract charts from pdf using python code. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

For extracting **tables** you can use [camelot](https://github.com/socialcopsdev/camelot/)

Here is an [article](https://hackernoon.com/announcing-camelot-a-python-library-to-extract-tabular-data-from-pdfs-605f8e63c2d5) about it.

For images I've found this question and answer [Extract images from PDF without resampling, in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693820/extract-images-from-pdf-without-resampling-in-python)

Comment: Images are more or less done. But the biggest challenges are those graphs aren't images, they're an amalgamation of texts, bars, lines and axises. I really am excited to know how people parse them out from high quality PDFs.

Comment: Getting this error: RuntimeError: Please make sure that Ghostscript is installed. Even though I've installed Ghostscript 9.27. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Try using PyMuPdf(https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/tree/1.18.3) for amalgamation of texts, bars, lines and axis. It has so many extra utilities.

Comment: check extract-graphics in this( https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF-Utilities)