# Python - Extract chart from .PDF files

Tags: python, pdf, extract

Using Python, I am trying to identify a chart area from PDF files, where these charts are **not** saved as images. As an example, I am trying to annotate (draw a rectangle) around the 4 charts on the page numbered 3 in
[this document](https://www.unilever.com/Images/unilever-charts-2018_tcm244-534891_en.pdf).

I found a [previous similar question asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55899363/how-to-extract-charts-tables-graphs-from-pdf-files-using-python), which refers to identification of graphs/ chart/ tables from a PDF,and the solutions quoted there are relevant to table extraction, whereas I am looking to identify/ extract these charts.

Comment: but then extract where you will save it ?...I mean ...format

Comment: As a first step, I just want to identify the chart area.

Comment: Hi willing_astronomer,
Curious to know how you managed to accomplish this. Especially identifying/extracting charts and graphs.