# How do I resolve "No module named 'frontend'" error message?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mupdf, pymupdf

I have installed PymuPDF/fitz because am trying to extract images from PDF files.  However, upon running the code below, I am seeing `No module named 'frontend'`.

```py
    doc = fitz.open(pdf_path)
            for i in range(len(doc)):
                for img in doc.getPageImageList(i):
                    xref = img[0]
                    pix = fitz.Pixmap(doc, xref)
                    if pix.n < 5:  # this is GRAY or RGB
                        pix.writePNG("p%s-%s.png" % (i, xref))
                    else:  # CMYK: convert to RGB first
                        pix1 = fitz.Pixmap(fitz.csRGB, pix)
                        pix1.writePNG("p%s-%s.png" % (i, xref))
                        pix1 = None
                    pix = None
```

I have searched but there isn't single report of this kind of error. I have installed PyMuPDF, muPDF and fitz modules

Here is the error in full:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/waqar/PycharmProjects/predator/ExtractFileImage.py", line 1, in <module>
        import fitz
      File "/home/waqar/anaconda3/envs/retinanet/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fitz/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from frontend import *
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'frontend'
```

Comment: I don't think you should have installed fitz, "Modern Nipype Workflow Management". (https://github.com/kastman/fitz), i would uninstall fitz. I see these instructions for installing PymuPDF on ubuntu: https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/wiki/Ubuntu-Installation-Experience

Comment: I am basically trying to use fitz module, PyMuPDF and mupdf they doesn't have some filters like unsupported filter /DCTDecode pypdf2 and few others

Answer (score 141, accepted):

I've solved it by:

```
pip install PyMuPDF
```

This will actually allow the import of the `fitz` you appear to want.  (There's [another fitz](https://github.com/kastman/fitz), which is probably not what you want if you're manipulating PDF files.)

NOTE: If you get `RuntimeError: Directory 'static/' does not exist` after install than do:

```
pip uninstall fitz
```

for more info see: [raise RuntimeError(f"Directory '{directory}' does not exist") RuntimeError: Directory 'static/' does not exist from import fitz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67982760/raise-runtimeerrorfdirectory-directory-does-not-exist-runtimeerror-dire)

Comment: fyi, case insensitive

Answer (score 38):

I tried the above solution of `pip install PyMuPDF`.
But it did not work out of the box.

So, I have used the previous version of PyMuPDF. It worked perfectly for me.

```
pip install PyMuPDF==1.16.14
```

Comment: This actually fixed the issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're right. I faced the same issue using PyMuPDF==1.20.2 and fixed it using PyMuPDF==1.21.1. It seems multiple versions are having issues.

Answer (score 9):

There is a package named `fitz` on PyPI. Because PyMuPDF uses the same name, `fitz`, as its top-level text, both packages cannot co-exist in the same Python - except with the aforementioned change.

Answer (score 6):

**Python3** and you have already installed **PyMuPDF** module.

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install -U PyMuPDF
```

Answer (score 5):

You should run `pip install fitz` follow by `pip install PyMuPDF`. If you have install PyMuPDF, uninstall it and install again.

Comment: I used below versions: fitz==0.0.1.dev2 and PyMuPDF==1.18.15 in the same order. Seems to work for me now.

Comment: Do not install `fitz` as it will give you a weird error when trying to use pymupdf.

Answer (score 4):

In file `/home/waqar/anaconda3/envs/retinanet/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fitz/__init__.py`

change

`from frontend` to `from fitz.frontend`

Comment: @Ryan  I tried this solution but still the error persists. I also noticed that in the _init_.py file, the print function looks more like python 2.7 version . Could the error be cause of that ?

Comment: @Ryan - I second the above comment. Making your change is now resulting in getting syntax error of 'print". Are they related?

Answer (score 3):

1. pip install PyMuPDF
2. If the above command has the error of fitz.h, then upgrade the python version, I found that python3.6.* will have this problem. If you cannot upgrade the python version, lower the version of pymupdf (version 1.18.0 is OK, pip install PyMuPDF==1.18.0).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.

Answer (score 0):

Calling python on your script should solve the issue:

```
python script.py
```

If you don't use the keyword python, you might get the error.

In my case I was getting:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fitz'
```

Answer (score 0):

This combo works fine for me:

```
sudo apt install mupdf
sudo apt install libmupdf-dev
pip3 install PyMuPDF==1.16
```

Answer (score -3):

You could have used pdfplumber. If the following code returns "None", it's a scanned pdf otherwise it's searchable.

```
with pdfplumber.open(file_name) as pdf:
    page = pdf.pages[0]
    text = page.extract_text()
    print(text)
```

To extract text from scanned pdf, you can use OCRmyPDF. Easy package