# raise RuntimeError(f"Directory '{directory}' does not exist") RuntimeError: Directory 'static/' does not exist from import fitz

Tags: python

I am getting this error when I run extract_img.py file:

> RuntimeError(f“Directory '{directory}' does not exist”)
> RuntimeError: Directory 'static/' does not exist from import fitz

I don't understand why this sends me back this error message.
I saw the conversation dealing with this topic before but I did not understand the solution. Could you help me?

This file is intended to extract certain images from a PDF filesome images in a file.

```
from os import chdir
import shutil, os
import io
from PIL import Image
import fitz
from unif_noun import unif_noun #other file python for change file noun.

def execute_func(rootdir):
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        filepath = subdir + os.sep + file
        if filepath.endswith(".pdf"):
            #extract(f"{filepath}")
            # open the file
            pdf_file = fitz.open(file)
            images = list()
            for page_index in range(len(pdf_file)):
                # get the page itself
                page = pdf_file[page_index]
                image_list = page.getImageList()
                # printing number of images found in this page
                # if image_list:
                #     print(f"[+] Found a total of {len(image_list)} images in page {page_index}")
                # else:
                #     print("[!] No images found on page", page_index)
                for image_index, img in enumerate(page.getImageList(), start=1):
                    images.append(img[0])
            for i, xref in enumerate(images, start=1):
                if 1 < i < len(images) - 3:
                    # extract the image bytes
                    base_image = pdf_file.extractImage(xref)
                    image_bytes = base_image["image"]
                    # get the image extension
                    image_ext = base_image["ext"]
                    # load it to PIL
                    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_bytes))
                    # save it to local disk
                    image.save(open(f"{unif_noun(file)}.{image_ext}", "wb"))
                    # Déplacer un fichier du répertoire
                    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
                        for f in files:
                            source = subdir
                            destination = 'C:/Users/.../VS Projects/img'
                            filename = os.path.basename(source)
                            dest = os.path.join(destination,filename)
                            shutil.move(source + f"{unif_noun(file)}.{image_ext}", dest)
execute_func(r'C:/Users/Factoryz Amandine/OneDrive/Bureau/Python/CCOR02752150_3.pdf')[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: If it's a hierarchy of directories, everything along the way has to exist. I think it would be clearer what is failing if you also showed a bit more of the call stack in the error message.

Answer (score 48):

**uninstall the existing fitz module/package**

```
pip uninstall fitz
```

**Install pymupdf module**

```
pip install pymupdf
```

source: [Unable to use fitz with python 3.8](https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/issues/523)

Comment: I asked chatGPT to understand the difference between the two.. quoting it: [quote] In summary, PyMuPDF is the overarching Python binding for the MuPDF library, and fitz is a specific module within PyMuPDF that deals with the document model for PDFs. When you use PyMuPDF, you will often find yourself using the fitz module to work with PDF documents in a more convenient and Pythonic way [/endquote].... So when you have pyMUPDF you also have fitz. The dependencies with pymuPDF seem to work better.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and installing `PyMuPDF` fixed it for me. ( Guess this is not the first time installing `PyMuPDF` solving other problems too with fitz )

```
pip3 install PyMuPDF
```