# How do I resolve "No module named 'frontend'" error message on Google Cloud Function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, google-cloud-functions, pymupdf

I'm trying to deploy a cloud function with Python 3.9 but when I run

```
gcloud functions deploy my_function --project my_project --runtime python39 --trigger-resource bucket_name --trigger-event google.storage.object.finalize
```

the deploy fails with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/bin/functions-framework", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(_cli())
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1128, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1053, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1395, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/functions_framework/_cli.py", line 37, in _cli
    app = create_app(target, source, signature_type)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/functions_framework/__init__.py", line 288, in create_app
    spec.loader.exec_module(source_module)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/workspace/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import fitz
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fitz/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from frontend import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'frontend'
```

I found a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56467667/how-do-i-resolve-no-module-named-frontend-error-message) but how can i install PyMuPDF in the cloud function? Shouldn't it install it by itself via the requirements.txt file?

Here's my directory structure:

```
── folder
   ├── main.py
   ├── requirements.txt
```

Here's my **main.py**:

```
import numpy as np
import fitz
import os
from google.cloud import storage

def my_function()
    do stuff with fitz
```

Here's my requirements.txt file:

> ```
> cachetools==4.2.4
> certifi==2021.10.8
> charset-normalizer==2.0.9
> ci-info==0.2.0
> click==8.0.3
> configobj==5.0.6
> configparser==5.2.0
> etelemetry==0.2.2
> filelock==3.4.0
> fitz==0.0.1.dev2
> future==0.18.2
> google-api-core==2.3.0
> google-auth==2.3.3
> google-cloud-core==2.2.1
> google-cloud-storage==1.43.0
> google-crc32c==1.3.0
> google-resumable-media==2.1.0
> googleapis-common-protos==1.54.0
> httplib2==0.20.2
> idna==3.3
> isodate==0.6.0
> lxml==4.6.4
> networkx==2.6.3
> nibabel==3.2.1
> nipype==1.7.0
> numpy==1.21.4
> packaging==21.3
> pandas==1.3.4
> pathlib==1.0.1
> protobuf==3.19.1
> prov==2.0.0
> pyasn1==0.4.8
> pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
> pydot==1.4.2
> PyMuPDF==1.19.2
> pyparsing==3.0.6
> python-dateutil==2.8.2
> pytz==2021.3
> pyxnat==1.4
> rdflib==6.0.2
> requests==2.26.0
> rsa==4.8
> scipy==1.7.3
> simplejson==3.17.6
> six==1.16.0
> traits==6.3.2
> urllib3==1.26.7
> joblib~=1.1.0
> ```

I created this list through `pip freeze> requirements.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the thread you linked, there are several solutions, and an [interesting one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62332877/16929894) seems to be that a package named `fitz` conflicts with `PyMuPDF`, as they both use the same top name inside a script (being `fitz`). I see both libraries are in your `requirements.txt`, so this could be the cause of this error. I tested adding both libraries inside a Cloud Function and received the same error, which was resolved after removing `fitz 0.0.1.dev2` from the file, and using only `PyMuPDF`.

You can see another example of this behavior from [this](https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/issues/220#issuecomment-759526939) GitHub issue.

Comment: Thanks man, I removed `fitz 0.0.1.dev2` from the `requirements.txt` file and everything works perfectly.