# Python3 install PyMuPDF Error creating Metadata (pyproject.toml)

Tags: python, tkinter, pip, pymupdf

I have a Python project running on my Raspberry Pi 4 to display `pdf` files. I was using `fitz` and `pymupdf` to display them.

It was working fine, until February 2024. Since then I always got the error "no module named frontend", when I tried to `import fitz`.

Because of this, I uninstalled `fitz` and installed `PyMuPDF` again, because of this question:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56467667/how-do-i-resolve-no-module-named-frontend-error-message
```

But when I want to install `PyMuPDF`. It always crashes when preparing metadata.

```
(Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... ) 
With the error: error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.
```

I also tried some older versions of `PyMuPDF`.  (1.23, 1.16.14,...). With older versions I get the error:

`Failed building wheel for PyMuPDF`.

Since I was not able to fix this problem, I also tried `tkPDFViewer`.
But this package seems also be based on `fitz`.  - I get the same errors here. (all starting with no module named "frontend")

Also tried pip install frontend.   - but then the next errors occur: "This error occured while importing neccesary modules or library Directory 'static/' does not exist".

I really don't know what I should try next. Why does `fitz / PyMuPDF` suddenly not work any more?

My code with `fitz` and `PyMuPDF` was running for almost a year now, without any problems.

I am using a 8GB Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye).
Python Version: 3.9.2

Please let me know if somebody have the same problems lately with `PyMuPdf` and `fitz`.

Older versions of `PyMuPDF`, `TkPdfViewer`, reinstall `fitz`, reinstall Python completely.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.