# Extract images from PDF in high resolution with Python

Tags: python, pdf, pymupdf

I have managed to extract images from several PDF pages with the below code, but the resolution is quite low. Is there a way to adjust that?

```
import fitz    
pdffile = "C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\myfile.pdf"
doc = fitz.open(pdffile)
for page_index in range(doc.pageCount):
    page = doc.loadPage(page_index)  
    pix = page.getPixmap()
    output = "image_page_" + str(page_index) + ".jpg"
    pix.writePNG(output)
```

I have also tried using the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693820/extract-images-from-pdf-without-resampling-in-python) and updated if pix.n < 5" to "if pix.n - pix.alpha < 4 but this didn't output any images in my case.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As stated in this issue for PyMuPDF, you have to use a matrix:
[issue on Github](https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/issues/181).

The example given is:

```py
zoom = 2    # zoom factor
mat = fitz.Matrix(zoom, zoom)
pix = page.getPixmap(matrix = mat, <...>)
```

Indicated in the issue is also that the default resolution is 72 dpi if you don't use a matrix which likely explains your getting low resolution.

Comment: Please everyone be reminded that camelCased names in PyMuPDF have been renamed to snake_cased versions - plus a few completely new names like `pix.writePNG` became `pix.save` and more like that. This happened in v1.18.4 and is mandatory since 1.20.0.

Answer (score 6):

Even simpler than making a matrix, the documentation for [`getPixmap()`](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/page.html#Page.get_pixmap) shows that you can use the `dpi` argument for higher resolution:

```py
pix = page.getPixmap(dpi=200)
```

This is new as of v1.19.2.

Comment: Thanks, i increased DPI to 500 and quality improved very much !!

Answer (score 0):

To get the best quality, use 'matrix' and 'dpi'. This code solve the problem of higher resolution of the result. I implement a solution to convert all files at the folder with the best quality:

```
# pip install fitz
# pip install pip install PyMuPDF==1.19.0

import fitz
import glob

for filename in glob.glob("*.pdf"):
    pdffile = filename
    doc = fitz.open(pdffile)
    for page_index in range(doc.pageCount):
        try:
            page = doc.load_page(page_index)  
            zoom = 2 
            mat = fitz.Matrix(zoom, zoom)
            pix = page.get_pixmap(matrix = mat,dpi=1200)
            output = '_' + filename.replace(".pdf","") + "-" + str(page_index) + ".png"
            pix.save(output)
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(filename) + ' > ' + str(e))    
    doc.close()
```