# Is there a way to extract images from a pdf in Python while preserving the location of the image in the pdf?

Tags: python, image, pdf, pdf-scraping

I need to extract images from a pdf without losing its location in the pdf. I need to know which page the image is on and where in the text the image is located, and then save the text and images in the pdf to a json file with the sequence of the data intact.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract images from PDF without resampling, in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693820/extract-images-from-pdf-without-resampling-in-python)

Comment: No, I do care about where the source image is located on the page :(

Answer (score 0):

You could use [pdfplumber](https://pypi.org/project/pdfplumber/) and run this code:

```
import pdfplumber

pdf_obj = pdfplumber.open(doc_path)
page = pdf_obj.pages[page_no]
images_in_page = page.images
page_height = page.height
image_bbox = (image['x0'], page_height - image['y1'], image['x1'], page_height - image['y0'])
cropped_page = page.crop(image_bbox)
image_obj = cropped_page.to_image(resolution=400)
image_obj.save(path_to_save_image)
```

Source link [here](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/get+coordinates+of+an+image+from+a+pdf+python)