# How to check QR Code available in PDF File using Python

Tags: python, pdf

I have been trying to extract the QR Code from PDF using python. When first need to see weather QR Code available in the PDF or not.

**Below the Code been attached on it:**

```
import PyPDF2
from pyzbar import pyzbar
from PIL import Image

def has_qr_code(pdf_path):
    pdf_file = open(pdf_path, 'rb')
    pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(pdf_file)

    for page in pdf_reader.pages:
        images = page.Extract_Image()
        for image in images:
            img = Image.fromarray(image)
            decoded = pyzbar.decode(img)
            if decoded:
                return True
    
    return False

# Example usage
pdf_path = r"C:\Users\TestData.PDF"
if has_qr_code(pdf_path):
    print("QR code found in the PDF.")
else:
    print("No QR code found in the PDF.")
```

On page.Extract Image getting Error : "**AttributeError**: 'PageObject' object has no attribute 'Extract_Image'"

Suggest !!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract images from PDF without resampling, in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693820/extract-images-from-pdf-without-resampling-in-python)

Comment: based on ocumentation, either page.Extractimage() or page.extract_images(), I couldn't find extract_image in the documentation, I believe it is a deprecated function of PIL deprecated package.

Comment: @Shorn - Have tried with it but couldn't find the Solution.

Comment: @AliMassoud - Can you please suggest what alternate we can use for it.