# ItextSharp and CCITTFaxDecode

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext

I'm currently trying to extract an image from a pdf file using iTextSharp.

The pdf is made from a scanner: it has a single page that contains one big image.

When looking at the file I find the following:

```
<< /Type /XObject /Subtype /Image /Name /Obj3 /Width 2480 /Height 3507 /ColorSpace /DeviceGray /BlackIs1  true /BitsPerComponent 1 /Length 5 0 R /Filter /CCITTFaxDecode /DecodeParms << /K -1 /Columns 2480 >> >> stream
```

I can access that using iTextSharp and I try to save it using the following code:

```
Dim aFromImageStream = New MemoryStream()
aFromImageStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
Dim anImage = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromStream(aFromImageStream, True, True)
anImage.Save("c:\test.tiff", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff)
```

But, that doesn't work as I get one big black tiff file with different shades of gray on top.

Does anyone know a way how I can decode those CCITTFaxDecode images?

Answer (score 1):

Please see answers for [Extracting image from PDF with /CCITTFaxDecode filter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2641770/249690) question.