# Free open-source Java library to convert PDF -Image, PDF - HTML, PDF - extract images and text

Tags: java, open-source, pdfbox

I need Java Library to perform following tasks  1) Convert Pdf pages to Image  2) Extract html text from PDF pages with there locations on the page  3) Extract images from PDF pages

I have already tried

1. PDFBox - it fails with error --unsupported/disabled operation: BDC and EMC
2. icePDF - it works for task 1) and 3) but again its paid.
3. PDFRenderer - it fails
4. BFO - its paid library but able to perform tasks 1) and 3)

Can anyone suggest better solution.

Comment: try iText http://itextpdf.com/

Comment: I suppose that is for Converting HTML to PDF, not vice versa

Comment: I'd be interested in such a Java library, too. At the moment we are using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poppler_(software) on Linux systems to do similar tasks.

Comment: @YashpalSingla itext can do this, i belive. For example - how to extract text from pdf: http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=275

Comment: and this may be helpful for extraction images http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851385/save-tiff-ccittfaxdecode-from-pdf-page-using-itext-and-java

Comment: Thanks @user1516873 i'll check both link

Comment: I have used pdfToHTML to get HTML from pdf in ubuntu and than i have used cutycapt to get image from it. Than i parsed that HTML to extract text with styling and locatoin using JSoup.Output was satisfactory to what i required.

Comment: "unsupported/disabled operation: BDC and EMC" is not an error, it is an INFO and is irrelevant to most PDF files.

Comment: @user1516873, iText is paid product and its license for single developer costs above $ 2k.

Comment: @deathrace No, it has dual licensing, for open-source project you can use AGPL version http://itextpdf.com/AGPL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have followed following steps to solve the issue in Ubuntu Enviornment

Step 1) Used pdftohtml library to convert pdf to html

Step 2) Used Jsoup to extract text with styling and position from html in step 1)

Step 3) Used CutyCapt to generate snapshot of HTML (if required)

We can also use
pdftoppm command to extract images directly from pdf

Comment: Singha All of them can be accomplished by using pdfbox

Comment: Its not singha its Singla, anyhow thanks for your comment

Comment: @Neeraj Can you provide me a link to an example of converting pdf to html using pdfbox.

Comment: @Rachit Agarwal: java -jar pdfbox-app-x.y.z.jar ExtractText -html <PDF file> <html file> http://neerajkarimpuzha.wordpress.com/2012/04/04/pdf-to-html-update/,      http://pdfbox.apache.org/commandlineutilities/ExtractText.html

Comment: Thanks..but i was looking forward to do this from java code. Not invoke it through command line arguments

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [JOD Converter](http://code.google.com/p/jodconverter/)? It's a Java API to a self-booted Open Office Server.

To see whether it converts to/from the formats you want, just install Open Office, open a file, and try to "Save As" the format you need, to see if it's supported.

Comment: Thanks @Stewart, i have tried JOD Converter, but the output is not useful as html

Answer (score -2):

You can do all those things with PDFBox. But for getting the position there is no API. Download the latest [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/download.html). Go to the following links to find your solutions.

1. [Convert Pdf pages to Image](http://pdfbox.apache.org/commandlineutilities/PDFToImage.html)
2. [Extract images from PDF pages](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/branches/before-maven-layout/src/org/pdfbox/ExtractImages.java)
3. Extract html text from PDF pages with there locations on the page is a little bit different. Using the API you will not get the position information. But you can get all the position information using PDFBox.

Please have a look at [this link](http://pdfbox.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/pdfbox/util/TextPosition.html). There you can see getTextPos() function. getTextPos().getXPosition(), getTextPos().getYPosition() will give you X and Y coordinates.

Comment: i have tried PDFBox already, as you can see in my post, but it results in BDC and EMC error, if you can help me in resolving that, that would be great

Comment: @singla : Please check the above links, and try it out. I have accomplished these with pdfbox. If you are getting errors, let me know

Comment: @Singla :converting to image and extract images can be done directly using api. Download pdfbox and please check the link..